# Splitting in multi line a multiline text at a specific line position

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a text file with this multi line structure:

```
12345 beautiful text in line01
95469 other text in line02
16987 nice text in line03
(etc...)
```

and want this:

```
12345
beautiful text in line01
95469
other text in line02
16987
nice text in line03
```

So, for every line, at position 5 i need a new line for the textual string.

Tried inserting `\n` with `string.Remove().Insert()` but works only for first line.
How can I do this?

EDIT
Code added by request
In input.txt there is the multiline textfile.

```
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
        string myString00 = myReader.ReadLine();

        string myStringFinal = myString00;
        myStringFinal = myStringFinal.Remove(5, 1).Insert(5, "\n");

        myReader.Close();
        FileStream myFs = new FileStream("output.txt", FileMode.Create);
        // First, save the standard output.
        TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
        StreamWriter mySw = new StreamWriter(myFs);
        Console.SetOut(mySw);
        Console.WriteLine(myStringFinal);
        Console.SetOut(tmp);
        Console.WriteLine(myStringFinal);
        mySw.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: just added the code i used

Comment: @akibau, you know you are only ever reading the first line. You are only calling `ReadLine()` once.

Comment: well .. i don't know if i know .. i'm a real newbie programmer, so i need 2/3 days to understand what all you have written and to make it work. 
thanks for now, you're amazing!

Comment: @akibau Sriram Sakthivel's Answer below uses Regex to find 5 digits and add a newline afterwards.  It's worth checking out.  If it solves your problem, make sure to Accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work only if the number is exactly 5 characters.

```
string input = @"12345 beautiful text in line01
95469 other text in line02
16987 nice text in line03";

var lines = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var formattedLines = lines
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Number = int.Parse(x.Substring(0, 5)),
        Data = x.Substring(5).TrimStart()
    })
    .ToList();
```

`formattedLines` will be a collection of your lines, with `Number` and `Data` holding the info from the lines.

```
var firstLinesData = formattedLines[0].Data;
```

So now, to make your output format:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in formattedLines)
{
    builder.AppendLine(item.Number.ToString());
    builder.AppendLine(item.Data);
}

string output = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I realized what you mean about ReadLine(). It's ok, original input file is one cluttered long line that becomes multiline after a series of string.replace i did, reaching `string myString07`.I have summarized the problem.
Well, tried your example and works with a small change. But the problem is that in the `string input = @""` i need to insert the cleaned multiline text that is now stored in `string myString07`. How can i pass that content to the `string input =` at first row of your example? Tried `string input = @myString07` but, again, only first row is processed, others remain undivided.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you can try with a `Regex`

```
var subject = @"12345 beautiful text in line01
95469 other text in line02
16987 nice text in line03";
var expected = Regex.Replace(subject,@"(\d{5})\s?","$1\r\n");
```

Basically this finds 5 digits followed by a space(optional), if found replaces it with digits and a new line. And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

loop over each line.  Use substring (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the first 5 character as a string.  Use a string builder and add the first part, grab the next part and add tot he string builder